# OS agnostic node builds

Tags: linux, node.js, windows, npm

I have a line like `"test": "NODE_ENV=test standard && grunt"` which works fine in linux but if I develop in windows `NODE_ENV` is not a recognizeable command in that environment. Is there a way to set env vars without taking in account OS?

Comment: You could try https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env

Comment: Cross-env solved the problem nicely, if you want you can post it as a response and I wiill accept it.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get a Windows environment to recognize new code types (i.e. php, bash, etc) and this might solve the problem on an individual basis. However you may ultimately need to add a repository/folder and a call to your code to get it to look within that included folder for the same functions if you are coding for an end product. (If I understood your problem correctly)